# how i can return a value after end recursive function in php

Tags: php

I need after the end of a loop in a recursive function to return the `$build` variable

This is my code:

```
    $traverse = function ($tree,$build = '') use (&$traverse) {

        foreach ($tree as $key=>$menu) {
            if (count($menu->children) > 0) {
                $build .= "<li ><a href='" . $menu->url . "'>" . $menu->text . "</a><ul>";
                    $traverse( $menu->children,$build);
                $build .= "</ul></li>";
            } else {
                $build .= "<li ><a href='" . $menu->url . "'>" . $menu->text . "</a></li>";
            }
        }
    };


 $traverse($tree );
```

Comment: Just add `return $build;` before the closing `}` of the function?

Comment: this way return just first loop and stop

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you could supply some sample input data and expected output...

Comment: this is nested set array , and each array have self children

Comment: Nick was correct: u should add `return $build;` before the closing `}` of the function. But also u should concat returned value inside the function - need to change `$traverse( $menu->children,$build);` to `$build .= $traverse( $menu->children,$build);`

Comment: please show with complete code . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment u should have:

```
$traverse = function ($tree) use (&$traverse) {

    $build = '';
    if (count($menu->children) > 0) {
        $build .= "<li ><a href='" . $menu->url . "'>" . $menu->text . "</a><ul>";
        $build .= $traverse($menu->children);
        $build .= "</ul></li>";
    } else {
        $build .= "<li ><a href='" . $menu->url . "'>" . $menu->text . "</a></li>";
    }

    return $build;
};
```

As u can see u also don't need to pass and use `$build` as argument to the function.

Also u should check the html code for being valid at the end. Because of it won`t be.